# jQuery UI Tabs- Setting parameters to NEXT/PREVIOUS button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am currently working with jQuery UI tabs, along with ajax. I have a total of 3 tabs which can only be navigated through "Next" & "Previous" buttons. I have set parameters: In tab1 if you leave input field `car_name` you will get an alert message and similar parameters with tab2.

*My intended set up:* if the parameter is not met then user can't advance to the next tab. However, that part is not working. The user gets an alert: which they can ignore, click next again, and advance to next tab. How can I disable the "next" button until parameter(fill out input field) is fulfilled? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/dropdown-menu/tabs.php)

thank you

**JS**

```
    <script>  
        $(function () {
            var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
              disabled: [0, 1, 2],
              select: function () {

                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "post_tabs.php",
                  data: {
                    "name": $("#car_name").val(),
                    "title": $("#title").val(),
                    "price": $("#price").val()

                  },
                  success: function (result) {
                    $("#tab-3").html(result);
                  } 
                });  
              } 
            });

            $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function (i) {
              var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;
              if (i != totalSize) {
                next = i + 2;
                $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
              }
              if (i != 0) {
                prev = i;
                $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
              }
            });



            $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function () {
              var prev = $(this).hasClass('prev-tab');
              var currentTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
              if (
                prev || /*(A)*/ (
                  currentTab == 0 && /*(B)*/
                  $.trim($('#car_name').val()).length > 0

                ) || (
                  currentTab == 1 && /*(C)*/
                  $.trim($('#title').val()).length > 0 && $.trim($('#price').val()).length > 0)


              ) {
                var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
                $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex).tabs('select', tabIndex).tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
              } else if (!prev) {
                switch (currentTab) {
                  case 0:
                    alert('Please choose an option.', 'Alert Dialog');
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    alert('Please fill out all the required fields.', 'Alert Dialog');
                    break;

                }
              }
              return false;
            });


     $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function () {
          var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
          $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex).tabs('select', tabIndex).tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
          return false;
      });
});
         </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
 <label for="car_name">Car Model</label>
     <input type="text" id="car_name" class="detail" name="car_name" value="" /> <br>

</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

     <label for="title">Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="60" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br>
     <label for="price">Price</label>
     <input type="text" id="price" name="price" size="60" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br>
</div>

<div id="tab-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something a bit strange in your code. You register "next" and "prev" twice...

That is not what you intended.

What you want is the following behavior :

1. If prev is clicked - always go prev
2. If next is clicked - go next only if required fields are fulfilled.

this means you should change the following

1. remove the `.prev-tab` selector from the first event - and remove any mention to `prev` vairable. This method should only handle `next`.
2. remove `next` from the second event binding, this one should only handle `prev`.

So your JavaScript will look like this :

```
   $('.next-tab').click(function () {

              var currentTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
              if (
                (
                  currentTab == 0 && /*(B)*/
                  $.trim($('#car_name').val()).length > 0

                ) || (
                  currentTab == 1 && /*(C)*/
                  $.trim($('#title').val()).length > 0 && $.trim($('#price').val()).length > 0
                )


              ) {
                var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
                $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex).tabs('select', tabIndex).tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
              } else {
                switch (currentTab) {
                  case 0:
                    alert('Please choose an option.', 'Alert Dialog');
                    break;
                  case 1:
                    alert('Please fill out all the required fields.', 'Alert Dialog');
                    break;

                }
              }
              console.log("preventing default");

              return false;
            });


     $('.prev-tab').click(function () {
          var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
          $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex).tabs('select', tabIndex).tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
          return false;
      });
```

This should resolve your problem.

You can see this in actions and download my resources at [my site](http://www.mograbi.info/stackoverflow/question_11909082/main.html)

The above will answer your problem.

Now, please allow me a chance to suggest a way to make you code a bit shorter for the "next" scenario.

right above the line `$('.next-tab').click(function () {` create the following function

```
function isEmpty( item ) { 
    return $.trim(item.val()).length <= 0;
}
```

Now - add `class='required'` on every input field that should not be empty when clicking `next`.

on each tab add `data-alert="The alert message you want to show"`

Now the HTML should look like this

```
<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" data-alert="Please choose an option.">
 <label for="car_name">Car Model</label>
     <input type="text" id="car_name" class="required detail" name="car_name" value="" /> <br>

</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" data-alert="Please fill out all the required fields.">
     <label for="title">Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="title" class="required" name="title" size="60" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br>
     <label for="price">Price</label>
     <input type="text" id="price" class="required" name="price" size="60" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br>
</div>
```

Now the JS code should be much smaller and much more maintainable (even if you add another tab with required fields - it should not change ) - here it is

```
$('.next-tab').click(function () {
              var $tab = $(this).closest(".ui-tabs-panel");
              var $requiredFields = $tab.find(".required");
              var canContinue = true;

              $requiredFields.each(function(index,item){
                console.log(["checking" , item]);
                if ( canContinue && isEmpty($(item))){ alert( $tab.attr("data-alert"), 'Alert Dialog' ); canContinue = false; }

              });
              if ( canContinue )
              {
                var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
                $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex).tabs('select', tabIndex).tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
              } 
              return false;
            });
```

Comment: Thank you! I was regestering "next" and "prev" twice. Good Catch!

Comment: I added some feedback about how to make the code easier to read/maintain. For your pleasure.

Comment: Very Nice! this is a way much better approach. Great Work my friend!

Comment: i have another request, check question: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911305/ajax-js-display-value-of-a-div-with-a-button-click)