# How can I display value of a div with a button click?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am currently working with a wmd editor and jQuery-UI tabs. I have created an ajax/js function that will submit (when next button is clicked) the `wmd-preview` value and then php echo the result in tab 2. The problem is that I am not getting any results displayed. I am not looking for the `textarea` value but the div `#wmd-preview` value. How can I display the value of the div `wmd-preview` through my ajax/function?

**JS**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
        disabled: [0, 1],
        select: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "post_tabs.php",
                data: {
                    "wmd": $("#wmd-preview").val(),
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#tab-2").html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function (i) {
        var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;
        if (i != totalSize) {
            next = i + 2;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
        }
        if (i != 0) {
            prev = i;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
        }
    });

    $('.next-tab').click(function () {
        var currentTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
        if (
        (
        currentTab == 0 && /*(B)*/
        $.trim($('#wmd-input').val()).length > 0
        )
        ) {
            var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
            $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex).tabs('select', tabIndex).tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1]);
        } else {
            switch (currentTab) {
            case 0:
                alert('Please fill out all the required fields.', 'Alert Dialog');
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log("preventing default");
        return false;
    });

    $('.prev-tab').click(function () {
        var tabIndex = $(this).attr("rel");
        $tabs.tabs('enable', tabIndex).tabs('select', tabIndex).tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1]);
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['wmd'])){
    $wmd = $_POST['wmd']; 
    echo ('<div id="text_result"><span class="resultval"><h2>Textarea Echo result:</h2>'.$wmd.'</span></div>');
                       }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
    <textarea id="wmd-input" name="wmd-input" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="6"></textarea>
    <div id="wmd-preview"></div>
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">

</div>
```

Comment: The issue is that you're disabling the tabs. Disabling the tabs essentially removes the click function. If that's the case, then your select method can never fire. Maybe you want to rethink your design?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I have the same function working with regular input fields.

Comment: You're using `$("#wmd-preview").val(),` .. you should use `val()` on input fields and `html()` on divs and such.. the correct thing for this scenario is `$("#wmd-input").val()`- this is the correct choice because it reflects reality better. The preview depends on more things other than user input - and you don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP code should start with `<?php` , yours start with `<?` which is incorrect.

When you see PHP code presented as text - it should tell you it is not running, this is why you keep getting output like `'.$wmd.''); } ?>` instead of real PHP echo output.

The other comment still stands as well - you should either use `$("#wmd-preview").html()` or `$("#wmd-input").val()` but you cannot use `val` on divs, it does not work.

In this scenario `$("#wmd-input").val()` is the better choice just because this is the reason `input` fields exist - to get input.

Let me know if there are more questions I can help with.

Comment: Perfect, Thankyou. I was not aware but now I understand the logic you have presented.